# XSLT - Form individual entries together in a group

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm relatively new to XSLT.

I'm trying to group individual XML entries with different names into a group, but all my previous attempts have failed.

Is that even possible or does XSLT reach its limits?

**This is my input:**

```
<DATA>
   <NAME_TO>abc_1</NAME_TO>
   <ZIP_TO>abc_1</ZIP_TO>
   <CITY_TO>abc_1</CITY_TO>
   <STREET_TO>abc_1</STREET_TO>
   <NAME_CARR>abc_2</NAME_CARR>
   <ZIP_CARR>abc_2</ZIP_CARR>
   <CITY_CARR>abc_2</CITY_CARR>
   <STREET_CARR>abc_2</STREET_CARR>
</DATA>
```

**This should be my output:**

```
<PARTNERS>
   <PARTNER>
      <PART>TO</PART>
      <NAME>abc_1</NAME>
      <ZIP>abc_1</ZIP>
      <CITY>abc_1</CITY>
      <STREET>abc_1</STREET>
   <PARTNER>
   <PARTNER>
      <PART>CARR</PART>
      <NAME>abc_2</NAME>
      <ZIP>abc_2</ZIP>
      <CITY>abc_2</CITY>
      <STREET>abc_2</STREET>
   <PARTNER>
<PARTNERS>
```

Comment: In all your questions regarding XSLT, please state which version of XSLT your processor supports.

Comment: It's very easy to write a transformation that handles this one example, but it's not clear from your question how generic the solution has to be: will the input always contain these 8 elements in this order, or can it vary, and if so how?

Comment: It's also useful to show your best attempt. This gives us a good indication of how much you know and where you got stuck, which helps us produce an appropriate level of explanation of the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/DATA"> 
    <PARTNERS>
        <PARTNER>
            <PART>TO</PART>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*[contains(name(), '_TO')]"/>
        </PARTNER>
        <PARTNER>
            <PART>CARR</PART>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*[contains(name(), '_CARR')]"/>
        </PARTNER>
    </PARTNERS>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="*"> 
    <xsl:element name="{substring-before(name(), '_')}">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

P.S. You could make this generic by [grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info) the elements by `substring-after(name(), '_')`.